# server gets `/customer/:id` instead of actual id

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Front End

```
customer.controller("single_customer", 
     function($scope, $http, $routeParams)
        {    
            $http.get('http://localhost:4000/customer/:id').then (function(data){
                // $scope.whichCustomer = $routeParams.id;
                $scope.customer = data;

                console.log($scope.customer)

            }).catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
            }); 


        }
);
```

Back-End

```
app.get("/customer/:id", (req, res) => {

    var user = String(req.params.id);
    console.log(user)

    Customers.find({id:user}, (err, items) => {
        if (err) res.status(500).send(err)

        res.status(200).send(items);
        console.log(items)
      });
    // console.log(Customers.find({id:user}));
    // res.send(Customers.find({id:user}));

   });
```

Mongoose schema

```
var Customers = mongoose.model('Customers',{
    id: {type:String , required:true} ,
    name: String ,
    city : String ,
    state : String ,
    gender : String ,
});
```

Comment: I would suggest to add a clearer title and also, it would help if you could better elaborate in words what the problem is. By doing so more people will be able to help you out.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass actual customer id in place of `:id` in your $http call? `$http.get('http://localhost:4000/customer/<customer id>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending id as shown below:

```
customer.controller("single_customer", 
     function($scope, $http, $routeParams)
        {    
       $http.get("http://localhost:4000/customer/"+$routeParams.id}).then (function(data){
                // $scope.whichCustomer = $routeParams.id;
                $scope.customer = data;

                console.log($scope.customer)

            }).catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
            }); 

);
```

Comment: I have a new issue .If you could help .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067133/no-console-log-answer-while-posting

Answer (score 0):

```
customer.controller("single_customer", 
     function($scope, $http, $routeParams)
        {
            // $scope.whichCustomer = $routeParams.id;
            var base = "http://localhost:4000/customer/"
            var url = base + $routeParams.id;   
            $http.get(url).then (function(response){
                $scope.customer = response.data;  
                console.log($scope.customer)

            }).catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
            });    
        }
);
```